ExtendedProperty to flags in ews-java-api
i want get my email's flagStatus and flagType(Today, Tomorrow, startdate, duedate etc...)!!
but i only get flagstatus....
Always flagType is Null!!!!
Please Help Me...
String flagged = null;
            ConversationId conversationId = email.getConversationId();
            if (conversationId != null) {
                Collection<Conversation> conversations = email.getService().findConversation(new ConversationIndexedItemView(pageSize, offset), email.getParentFolderId());
                for (Conversation conversation : conversations) {
                    if (conversation.getId().equals(conversationId)) {
                        flagged = conversation.getFlagStatus().toString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            String flagType = null;
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition taskFlagStatusProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
                    DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, 0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
            List<ExtendedProperty> extendedProperties = item.getExtendedProperties().getItems();
            for (ExtendedProperty property : extendedProperties) {
                if (property.getPropertyDefinition().equals(taskFlagStatusProp)) {
                    int flagStatus = (Integer) property.getValue();
                    switch (flagStatus) {
                        case 1:
                            flagType = "Today";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            flagType = "Tomorrow";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            flagType = "This week";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            flagType = "Nest week";
                            break;
                        default:
                            flagType = "NoDate";
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(flagType);


That is not how PR_FLAG_STATUS MAPI property is used - its only values are 0 (no flag), 1 (complete), 2 (marked). When you mark a message for today/tomorrow/next week, Outlook sets the date/time task properties, such as TaskDueDate/TaskStartDate/etc (all named properties).
Take a look at a marked message with OutlookSpy (I am its author) - click IMessage button and see which property makes sense to retrieve in your case.
Also, your ExtendedPropertyDefinition() constructor is wrong, that is why you get back null: (0x1090, PT_LONG) is a fixed property tag, therefore you need
new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Long)

Your code implies a named MAPI property which is defined using GUID, prop name (int or string) and property type. You'd need to use that if you try to retrieve a named property (they are shown bold by OutlookSpy in the IMessage window).
